# Mouse Over Region Not Covering Entire Div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, mouseover

I have an arrow on the middle right side of my side which when mouse over, reveals a sidebar, and when each icon of that sidebar is clicked, the sidebar extends revealing content. The sidebar content collapses back once the user mouses out of the sidebar. My website is [here](http://ninjawarrior.info/new/index.html) (mouse over the arrow on the right and then click one of the icons and then mouse out to see my issue). The problem is, the sidebar collapses while the mouse is still over the sidebar.

It's as if the region of the sidebar the is considered "moused over" is different than the region of the sidebar shown.

The code I'm referring to is below

**HTML**

```
<div id="sidebar">
<div id="newsbar" class="icon"><img src="images/icons/whatsnew.png" width="70" height="70" alt="Ninja Warrior News"></div>
<div class="sidebarinfocontent" id="newscontent"><h1>Latest</h1>
                <p>The past few months, I have been working on a brand new website design and am delighted to finally be able to present it to you. This new design features a brand new comprehensive sidebar which greatly enhances both the look and the breakdown of content on the website. In addition, there is a slightly modified navigation bar with new red and blue colored buttons. You will also find that the background of the site has changed from a red and brown gradient to a solid black which does not clash nearly as much with the banner and with content. Let us know what you think in the feedback section.</p>
                <p>&nbsp;</p>
                <h2 align="center" style="padding-bottom:5px;">How Many Pageviews?</h2>
                <iframe src="http://www.seethestats.com/stats/11594/Pageviews_9ec4cf0b2_ifr.html" style="width:270px;height:142px;border:none;" scrolling="no" frameborder="0"></iframe></div>
```

**JQuery**

```
//sidebar appearance
$("#sidebar").mouseout(function(e) {
    $("#sidebar").css("right","-120px");
    $("#arrow").fadeIn(1200);
});

$("#arrow").mouseover(function(e) {
    $("#sidebar").css("right","0px");
    $("#arrow").fadeOut(400);
});

$("#sidebar").mouseover(function(e) {
    $("#sidebar").css("right","0px");
    $("#arrow").fadeOut(400);
});

$(".icon").click(function(e) {
    $(".sidebarinfo").css("right","0px");
    $("#sidebar").css("right","-120px");
});

$(".sidebarinfo").mouseout(function(e) {
    $(".sidebarinfo").css("right","-290px");
    $(".sidebarinfocontent").css("display","none");
});



//Sidebar individual icon clicks
$("#newsbar").click(function(e) {
    $("#newscontent").css("display","block");
});
```

Comment: I went to your site - when I mouse over the arrow - the sidebar comes out - it stays as long as my mouse is on it...isn't this what you want?

Comment: But when you move the mouse up, for example if you click the search icon and go to click on the search, it disappears. There is some region that counts as "moused over" but not the entire sidebar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After read all your comment, I have tested your site in my local and I have fixed the issue. It is really difficult to explain everything here. It is all about the logic thinking only. So that i am going to give the exact answer.

You need to update your main.js file with the following script. Only one section you have given in your question. But Here i am going to give two sections. You need to update both the section in your code.

```
 // Sidebar appearance
 $("#sidebar").mouseout(function(e) {
  $("#sidebar").css("right","-120px");
  $("#arrow").fadeIn(1200);
});

 $("#arrow").mouseover(function(e) {
   $("#sidebar").css("right","0px");
   $("#arrow").fadeOut(400);
 });

 $("#sidebar").mouseover(function(e) {
  $("#sidebar").css("right","0px");
 });

 $(".icon").click(function(e) {
   $(".sidebarinfo").css("right","0px");
   $("#sidebar").css("right","-120px");
 });

 $(".sidebarinfo").mouseout(function(e) {
   $(".sidebarinfo").css("right","-290px");
   $("#sidebar").css("right","-120px"); 
 });
 $(".sidebarinfocontent").mouseover(function(){
   $('.sidebarinfo').css("display","block");
   $(".sidebarinfo").css("right","0px");
 });


//Sidebar individual icon clicks
$("#newsbar").click(function(e) {
  $(".sidebarinfocontent").css("display","none");
  $("#newscontent").css("display","block"); 
});

$("#obstaclesbar").click(function(e) {
     $(".sidebarinfocontent").css("display","none");
    $("#getobstaclescontent").css("display","block");
});

$("#aboutmebar").click(function(e) {
     $(".sidebarinfocontent").css("display","none");
    $("#aboutmecontent").css("display","block");
});

$("#searchbar").click(function(e) {
     $(".sidebarinfocontent").css("display","none");
    $("#searchcontent").css("display","block");
});

$("#quizbar").click(function(e) {
     $(".sidebarinfocontent").css("display","none");
    $("#quizcontent").css("display","block");
});

$("#contactbar").click(function(e) {
     $(".sidebarinfocontent").css("display","none");
    $("#contactcontent").css("display","block");
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it still seems to be having the same problem. For example, if you click the magnifying glass icon, and then mouse your mouse to type in the searchbar, the sidebar moves back in before you can.

Comment: I think in that case we can use your old code and just remove fadeout effect of arrow in sidebar hover function. I just updated my answer with "edit" text. Check it out.

Comment: Still same issue. You can look at my code on the site. I made all the changes.

Comment: Ok. Finally i tested it in my local and fix the problem. I have updated my answer, check it out. Hopefully this time it will work everything.